# Hibernate Criteria Example

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, desktop-application, criteria

I have   tables 'Stores' and 'Item' . Item table has columns 'Category' , 'Brand' , 'itemcode'. 
Also I keep category details and brand details in another 2 tables called Category and Brands. Stores table has locums called item and qty. My hibernate entity classes are Stores, Item,Category,Brand.
I want to get items from stores for a given item with hibernate.Setting catagory and brand names for the item are done according to the user's preference.(That means, user selects the category and brand from a swing User interface,then application has to set an item with given category and brand name.) Items should be selected according to the given item from stores. here how I did:

```
 Stores stores = new Stores();  

 Item item = new Item();  
 if (isBrandNameMode()) {  //here checks if user select a brand in IF clause
     item.setBrands(selectedBrand);  
     //selectedBrand is an brand object which user selected  
 }  

 if (isCategoryode()) {// here checks if user select a category in IF clause
     item.setSizeModel(selectedSize);  
     //user selected 
 }   

 Criteria cr=HSession.getSession().createCriteria(Stores.class);  
 cr.add(Restrictions.eq("item", item));  
 List l=cr.list();  
 System.out.println("list size is: "+l.size());
```

But here all stores items are returned but not for the given item.
also I tried with `Critataria Example`

`stores.setItem(item);

cr.add(Example.create(stores))`  but returned all items in the stores. How can I get items from stores according to a given item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined equals/hashcode in your Item class?

Comment: Yes,for the item class, equal method was overridden.

Comment: What is the relation between Stores and Item?
Why call your object _Stores_ in plural and not _Store_?

Comment: How are equals/hashcode defined? Do you happen to use the id field?

Comment: Store table has items's quantity. equa method has been overriden with item's id.

Comment: It's not ok to put the id in the equals method (especially if it's automatically generated by hibernate), you really should choose another business key. See here an explanation: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode

Answer (score 0):

```
               Criteria crt=session.createCriteria(Product.class);            
            List<Product> l=crt.list();
            for(Product p:l)
            {
                System.out.println(p.getPrice());
                System.out.println(p.getProductId());
                System.out.println(p.getProName()); 
            }
```

Comment: Please post more than code only answers, it should be supported by some text.